# Conflict between github.io and github-pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a project in https://chrisbg69.github.io Days after that i create a react app and deploy static files at https://chrisbg69.github.io/portfolio in new repo called portfolio. When i visit app page for first time, she show only header with address .../portfolio. Next, when clicking any of buttons there, opened full app pages, like i expected, but address was changed to https://chrisbg69.github.io not https://chrisbg69.github.io/portfolio. How can i fix that i want both of projects published?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you don't have a route for `/parfolio/` in your react/redux router or it not configured properly, so when you entered only the header displayed and the content that your JS router should display is remain empty.

Because `/parfolio/` is your app index page in github.io you need to update all your internal routs to look like this `/parfolio/resume`, `/parfolio/aboutme`

Comment: With this method i can't develop the project, any way in the build folder i see service-worker.js Paths in this file are correct /portfolio/index.html etc...

Comment: unlike `/resume` which is internal react route, `/portfolio/index.html` is a real path to file in your project.